# Defining a button in TD1204

Tags: microcontroller

I am trying to define a button that is connected in the PIN 5

// Push button initialization

```
SwitchId = TD_TOOLS_SWITCH_Init(USR0_PORT, 5 , gpioModeInputPull, true, true, 2, 5, 8);
```

then I start polling but nothing happens when I push the button

Comment: What other interrupts have you set up? Some combinations cannot work, because they use the same interrupt lines, check http://community.td-next.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=79

Comment: no other ones, I just took the example from switch_polling.c